# HPE DL560 Gen8 Power fault detected. What does that mean?

Tags: hp-proliant, electrical-power

my DL560 Gwen 8 generated this problem.

> System Power Fault Detected (XR: 14 00 MID: FF 0D F0 0C C0 FF FF 0A 0A 0C 0C 00 9C 40 00 01 03 47 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00)

and powerd off rapidly. After detecting the offline server, I powered it on again and everything seems to be working fine. But is that only an environmental influence (No UPS is placed in front of the Server) or an error in the server hardware? Can someone decode that message?

Thanks!

---

[image: IML Screenshot]

Thats a screenshot of IML only this cryptic message.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this site](https://community.hpe.com/t5/ProLiant-Servers-ML-DL-SL/Problems-with-Proliant-DL560-Gen-8/td-p/6095739), seems you need to update your BIOS to last version

https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c04042380

Answer (score 1):

You should read the contents of the server's IML log and report back. Access this from within the operating system or by logging into the ILO.

This is where system events and faults are recorded. The general advice of updating the system and component firmware is fine, but you should understand what happened as well.

HP says this was fixed in the 8/2014 firmware listed in this advisory:
https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c04541663

> Following recommendations by Intel, HP has disabled the SETVID-Decay
>   functionality of the CPU via a System ROM update.
>
> The System ROM updates are available as follows:
>
> ProLiant DL560 Gen8 and ProLiant BL660c Gen8 server blades:
>
> This issue has been corrected in the System ROM dated 8/2/2014.

Comment: The message posted above is from IML

Comment: @JanRosum What is the firmware revision of the server?

Comment: @JanRosum See my update.